# SELECT Using LIMIT

Tags: sql, ms-access

I realise Access SQL doesn't have a LIMIT instruction, so I tried this:

```
UPDATE Master SET [Allocated To] = "Jessica"
WHERE [Case] IN (SELECT TOP 3 [Case] FROM Master WHERE [Created on] = "04/01/2017" AND Status IS NULL ORDER BY [Case])
```

This gives me an error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" but the data looks OK to me.

ie:
"Allocated To" is text

"Case" is Primary Key and numeric

"Created On" is Date/Time

Comment: Isn't "Created On" being treated as text in your query?  Try #04/01/2017# (or is it #01/04/2017#).

Comment: Above is correct. Dates use `#` instead of quotes. Exact format depends on regional settings. Whatever is a valid date where you are.